# Wallet loading failed: Prune: last wallet synchronisation goes beyond pruned data. You need to -reindex

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have bitcoin core installed, with a sub wallet with some bitcoin on it. The default wallet appears to be working fine, but when I try to open the sub wallet with bitcoin on it, I get the error message

> Wallet loading failed: Prune: last wallet synchronisation goes beyond pruned data. You need to -reindex. (download the whole blockchain again in case of pruned node)

and I am unable to open it. The prune settings are the default 2GB block storage and 450MiB size of database cache. I have reindexed Bitcoin Core one time but that did not help the problem, and I still get the error message every time I attempt to open the sub wallet.

[debug.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XAf-Nhz4G7uQBYJZWMB5nbcdIZl4mf91/view?usp=sharing)

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem for the moment by reindexing the entire bitcoin core wallet, making sure that pruning was disabled in the settings. This allowed me to access my funds again. I'm not sure what caused the issue in the first place.

Comment: Hey! I have the same issue - do you mean you actualy had to re-download the 300+ GB of data to solve the issue?

Comment: Hello, yes I did. It was quite frustrating.

Comment: I'm still running into this situation in 2024. I have some Bitcoin Core windows apps that make it clear a pruned node can run a wallet indefinitely but once on windows, when restoring a wallet, it happened, and with some recent linux cli experimentation it's been happening every few days.